# Office Word add-in error

Tags: email-template, office-connect

A user recently started getting the following error when using Salesforce.com Office Edition Word add-in to try and open (and subsequently edit) a mail merge template:

> An internal server error has occured while processing your request.
>
> Url: https://www.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/2.5

I noticed there is a single [question](http://success.salesforce.com/questionDetail?qid=a1X30000000f3csEAA) on the community page detailing the same question recently, but without an answer. Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: The number is API version, I've never heard about a fractional though. Can you try inspecting the Visual Basic code behind the plugin? Try to find this URL and change to "26.0" for example.

Comment: I actually just got word that the issue was a password issue (missing security token). Sometimes I forget to test the easiest solution first.

Comment: Eh, same here ;) Please consider answering the question yourself & marking as accepted? That way it'll go off the radar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer in this particular case was the user forgetting to append their security token to their password :)